# How to remove required from the field of the child form symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have 2 forms. For the child form, I need to delete required for selective fields.

CourseType form:

```
class CourseType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('contactName', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Enter Contact name'
            ]])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'));
    }
}
```

BulkCourseUpdate form:

```
class BulkCourseType extends CourseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->add('ids', HiddenType::class, array(
            'data' => $options['ids'],
            'mapped' => false
        ));

        //need to remove required for contactName field
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'ids' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

What's the easiest way to remove this attribute in the example above?

Comment: in options pass `'required' => false`.

Comment: How pass `'required' => false` for the `BulkCourseType` form for the `contactName` field from `CourseType`?

Comment: in `configureOptions` method.

Comment: This is easier than my answer from below?

Comment: It depends on use case, if you need to make this form optional in everywhere it gets used then my solutions works good, otherwise your solution works good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
$builder->get('contactName')->setRequired(false);
```

Thanks to all

Comment: To cancel `required` on all form fields, you can define the following in the `configureOptions` of the `$resolver->setDefaults(['required' => false,]);`